# JS/CSS Applying CSS transform to an element that is already transformed without losing original transformation

Tags: javascript, css, transform, css-transforms

I'm making some cards and movements of them as a starting point for several projects. I have run into a problem when trying to make a card shake. Because the card has already been flipped, when I move it side to side, it removes the flip when it shakes.

I've put the problem code in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mb94ef58/). Click both cards to flip them, click one to select it (moves up) and then click the second to make it shake (to show not being selected), the back shows instead of the front.

I have tried playing with z-index, opacity, display, and duplicating the rotated 180 in the animation.

The closest I got was using :not, but it only shook the text in the card, not the whole card

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Code from Fiddle :

```js
let selectLimit = parseInt(document.getElementById("numSelectLimit").value);
let currentlySelected = [];

function onInput() {
  selectLimit = parseInt(document.getElementById("numSelectLimit").value);
}

function clickFlip4(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("cardFlipped");
  element.setAttribute("onclick", "clickSelect3(this)");
}

function clickSelect3(element) {
  if (element.classList.contains("selected3")) {
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < currentlySelected.length; i++) {
      if (currentlySelected[i] === element) continue;
      else newArray[newArray.length] = element;
    }
    currentlySelected = newArray;
    element.classList.toggle("selected3");
  } else {
    if (currentlySelected.length !== selectLimit) {
      currentlySelected[currentlySelected.length] = element;
      element.classList.toggle("selected3");
    } else {
      element.classList.toggle("shake");
      setTimeout(function() {
        element.classList.toggle("shake");
      }, 500); //500 matches animation length of .05 seconds    
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 275px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  display: inline-block;
  /*
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
*/
  padding: 65px 3px;
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.cardInner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.cardFlipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.cardBack,
.cardFront {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.cardBack {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.cardFront {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.selected,
.selected2,
.selected3 {
  margin-top: -60px;
}

form,
label,
input {
  font: inherit;
}

.shake {
  animation: horizontal-shaking 0.5s;
}

@keyframes horizontal-shaking {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(5px)
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateX(-5px)
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(5px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-5px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <form onsubmit="return false">
    <label for="selectLimit"> Select Limit:</label>
    <input id="numSelectLimit" name="selectLimit" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" oninput="onInput()">
  </form>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardInner" onclick="clickFlip4(this)">
      <div class="cardBack">
        <p>BACK</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cardFront">
        <p>FRONT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="cardInner" onclick="clickFlip4(this)">
      <div class="cardBack">
        <p>BACK</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cardFront">
        <p>FRONT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an annoying situation. Additional class with a transform property will override the previous transform making it impossible to achieve your desired result.

However, there are a couple of ways we can solve this issue:

1. Wrap the **.cardInner** element with a <div> tag, and apply the shaking animation to that wrapper instead. OR,
2. Second approach requires some modifications to the function responsible for the flipping.

> Before the card is flipped: DISPLAY the BACK element.
>
> After the flip animation is done: REMOVE all transitions and DISPLAY
> only the FRONT element.

This will allow you to apply the NEW shaking animation as you can finally focus only on the currently displayed element.

Just update your clickFlip4() to the following:

```
function clickFlip4(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("cardFlipped");
    element.removeAttribute("onclick");
    element.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {

        let back  = element.querySelector('.cardBack');
        let front = element.querySelector('.cardFront');

        back.style.display = "none";
        front.style.transform = "none";

        element.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        element.style.transform = "none";
        element.setAttribute("onclick", "clickSelect3(this)");

    }, { once: true });
}
```

Here is also the snippet just in case:

```js
let selectLimit = parseInt(document.getElementById("numSelectLimit").value);
let currentlySelected = [];

function onInput() {
    selectLimit = parseInt(document.getElementById("numSelectLimit").value);
}

function clickFlip4(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("cardFlipped");
    element.removeAttribute("onclick");
    element.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {

        let back  = element.querySelector('.cardBack');
        let front = element.querySelector('.cardFront');

        back.style.display = "none";
        front.style.transform = "none";

        element.style.transitionDuration = "0s";
        element.style.transform = "none";
        element.setAttribute("onclick", "clickSelect3(this)");

    }, { once: true });
}

function clickSelect3(element) {
    if (element.classList.contains("selected3")) {
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < currentlySelected.length; i++) {
            if (currentlySelected[i] === element) continue;
            else newArray[newArray.length] = element;
        }
        currentlySelected = newArray;
        element.classList.toggle("selected3");
    }
    else {
        if (currentlySelected.length !== selectLimit) {
            currentlySelected[currentlySelected.length] = element;
            element.classList.toggle("selected3");
        }
        else {
            element.classList.toggle("shake");
            setTimeout( function() {
                element.classList.toggle("shake");
            }, 500);         //500 matches animation length of .05 seconds  
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.card {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 275px;
    height: 400px;
    perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
    display: inline-block;
/*
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
*/
    padding: 65px 3px;
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.cardInner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.cardFlipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.cardBack, .cardFront {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.cardBack {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
}

/* Style the back side */
.cardFront {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.selected, .selected2, .selected3 {
    margin-top: -60px;
}

form, label, input {
    font: inherit;
}

.shake {
    animation: horizontal-shaking 0.5s;
}
    @keyframes horizontal-shaking {
        0% { transform: translateX(0) }
        20% { transform: translateX(5px) }
        40% { transform: translateX(-5px) }
        60% { transform: translateX(5px) }
        80% { transform: translateX(-5px) }
        100% { transform: translateX(0) }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <label for="selectLimit"> Select Limit:</label>
  <input id="numSelectLimit" name="selectLimit" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" oninput="onInput()">
</form>

<div class="card">
  <div class="cardInner" onclick="clickFlip4(this)">
    <div class="cardBack">
      <p>BACK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cardFront">
      <p>FRONT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="cardInner" onclick="clickFlip4(this)">
    <div class="cardBack">
      <p>BACK</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cardFront">
      <p>FRONT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was great! I had to rework how I was implementing the array as it wouldn't work if you selected and deselected a few times, but this was only ever a stepping stone to something more, so there's space to add that in later.